# Selecting count(*) from multiple tables in one resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

How I can select count(*) for 30 tables with other fields.

I want to apply restriction like time constraint.  I have tables like `statemaster`, `dealermaster`, `businessdetail`.

I want results for  respective `statecode`, `statename`.

i want output like:-

```
statecode statename count(*) for dealermaster count(*) for business details
01        ca         25                        20
01        au         30                        35
```

statecode, statename from statemaster table

Comment: You need to provide more detail.  Table schema and your work so far.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst this sounds like an odd request, I'll provide an answer anyway and see how you get along with it.

You should be able to use a bunch of correlated subqueries to obtain these results, as in...

```
SELECT S.statecode,
       S.statename,
       (
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM dealermaster DM
              WHERE DM.statecode = S.statecode
       ) AS COUNT1,
       (
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM businessdetail BD
              WHERE BD.statecode = S.statecode
       ) AS COUNT2
FROM statemaster S
GROUP BY S.statecode, S.statename
```